# Backbone model url fails when route doesn't contain leading slash

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

My app is deployed on a server that is not on the root:

```
http://www.myserver.com/myApp/
```

I've a route set up in backbone to execute on the root of the above url:

```
routes: {
    '*path': 'index'
}
```

In my index function I set up a model and view and call fetch on that model, which works fine.  The model requests the url:

```
http://www.myserver.com/myApp/myData.json
```

The problem is when I go to the url without the training slash:

```
http://www.myserver.com/myApp
```

My app loads but my model.fetch() call fails because it try to get the data from:

```
http://www.myserver.com/myData.json
```

Has anyone any ideas?

I'm not using pushstate: true on the history and setting root in the history.start() doesn't seem to do anything:

```
router.init();
Backbone.history.start({ root: '/myapp/' });
```

As far as I can see the root param is only used when pushState is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

Set the root path for your routes in your call to Backbone.history.start():

```
Backbone.history.start({ root: 'myApp' });
```

Otherwise, the root of your site will be assumed.

Comment: This still doesn't work for me. I've debugged the backbone source code and I can't see where root is applied to the model/collection fetch url.  I think it's only applied when pushState is true.

Comment: To clarify, the root value is applied when it's parsing your routes. For the api calls, you specify the root in the definition of your collection constructor. I don't think I'm completely clear on the nature of the problem you're having.